# What's the difference between BIO_pending() and BIO_wpending() in openssl?

Tags: openssl

I checked the [BIO pending](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_pending.html) on Openssl man page.
Failed to get the difference between *_pening and *_wpending.
Could you share the difference.
Thanks.

```
 int BIO_pending(BIO *b);
 int BIO_wpending(BIO *b);
 size_t BIO_ctrl_pending(BIO *b);
 size_t BIO_ctrl_wpending(BIO *b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BIO_pending` returns the amount of data waiting in the BIO's "read" buffer i.e. stuff that it has already read internally but has not yet been returned to the application via a `BIO_read()` call (or similar).

`BIO_wpending` returns the amount of data waiting in the BIO's "write" buffer, i.e. stuff that the application has asked the BIO to write via a call to `BIO_write` (or similar), but the BIO hasn't actually written yet.